# setup script remove atribute group from attribute set

Tags: product-attribute, attribute-set, installer

I have setup script which create a new attribute set. And i need remove attribute groups  "Gift Options" and  "Recurring Profile" from created attribute set. How can I do this?

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$inheritBase  = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId('catalog_product');

$attributeSetName = 'Custom Name';
$ignoreAttributes = array(
    'news_from_date'  => 'news_from_date',
    'news_to_date' => 'news_to_date',
    'weight'  => 'weight',
    'country_of_manufacture' => 'country_of_manufacture',
    'manufacturer' => 'manufacturer',
    'featured'  => 'featured',
    'color' => 'color',
    'delivery_time'  => 'delivery_time',
    'shipping_charges' => 'shipping_charges',
    'marketplace_state'  => 'marketplace_state',
    'generate_meta' => 'generate_meta',
    'percent_donat'  => 'percent_donat',
    'organization_charity' => 'organization_charity',
    'gift_message_available' => 'gift_message_available',
    'recurring_profile' => 'recurring_profile',
    'is_recurring' => 'is_recurring'
);
$installer->addAttributeSet('catalog_product', $attributeSetName);


$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->setAttributeSetFilter($inheritBase) 
    ->load();

$currentSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->setAttributeSetFilter($installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attributeSetName))
    ->load();

$aCurrentGroups = array();
foreach($currentSet AS $group)
{
    $aCurrentGroups[$group->attribute_group_name] = array("id" => $group->getId(), "sort_order" => $group->sort_order);
}

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $groupId = 0;
    $sort_order = 0;

    if(!isset($aCurrentGroups[$group->attribute_group_name])) {
        $installer->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetName, $group->attribute_group_name, $group->sort_order);
        $newGroup = $installer->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetName, $group->attribute_group_name);
        $groupId = $newGroup['attribute_group_id'];
        $sort_order = $newGroup['sort_order'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $aCurrentGroups[$group->attribute_group_name]["id"];             
        $sort_order = $aCurrentGroups[$group->attribute_group_name]["sort_order"];
    }

    $groupAttributesCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
        ->load();

    foreach ($groupAttributesCollection as $attribute) {
        if(!isset($ignoreAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()])) {
            $installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetName, $groupId, $attribute->getId(), $attribute->sort_order);
        }
    }
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code to remove the specific group and specific attributes while creating new attribute set by script. It works for me,

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$attributeSetName = 'Custom Name'; 

$ignoreGroup = array('Gift Options','Recurring Profile');//Add Attribute Group Name To Remove

$ignoreAttribute = array('news_to_date','weight','news_from_date');//Add Attribute Code to Remove

$entityTypeId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY;
$installer->addAttributeSet($entityTypeId,$attributeSetName,0);
$inheritBase = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$newAttributeSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId,$attributeSetName);

$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->getResourceCollection()->setAttributeSetFilter($inheritBase)->load();
foreach($groups as $group){
    if(!in_array($group->getAttributeGroupName(),$ignoreGroup))
    {
        $installer->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId,$newAttributeSetId,$group->getAttributeGroupName(),$group->getSortOrder());//Add Group To new Attribute Set

        $newGroup = $installer->getAttributeGroup($entityTypeId,$newAttributeSetId,$group->getAttributeGroupName());

        $attributeCollections = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getResourceCollection()->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())->load();
        foreach($attributeCollections as $attribute){
            if(!in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(),$ignoreAttribute))
            {
                $installer->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId,$newAttributeSetId,$newGroup['attribute_group_id'],$attribute->getId(),$attribute->getSortOrder());
            }
        }
    }
}
$installer->endSetup();
```